# WLAN 5GHz there is no channel 37

Tags: wireless

Why there is no channel 37 in WLAN 5 GHz band. what is the reason behind it

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

The original channel designations assumed 5 MHz spacing, and were made long before anyone thought of Wi-Fi.  Since Wi-fi signals are 20 MHz wide, they take up 4 channels.

So there is a channel 37 (and 38, and 39 ...), but it is part of the 20MHz bandwidth of a single Wi-fi signal (using channel 36).